# Optaplanner Quarkus reflection issues

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

I'm creating a solver factory based on an XML file using the built in

```
solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("solverConfig.xml");
```

This works fine until compiling into a Quarkus native application, now I get reflection issues from Optaplanner enums:

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.optaplanner.core.api.domain.common.DomainAccessType: REFLECTION
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getEnumConstants(ReflectionNavigator.java:25)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getEnumConstants(ReflectionNavigator.java:34)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.EnumLeafInfoImpl.calcConstants(EnumLeafInfoImpl.java:117)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.EnumLeafInfoImpl.getConstants(EnumLeafInfoImpl.java:181)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.EnumLeafInfoImpl.link(EnumLeafInfoImpl.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.link(ModelBuilder.java:427)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.link(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:439)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:273)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1126)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:275)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:264)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:403)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.io.jaxb.GenericJaxbIO.<init>(GenericJaxbIO.java:89)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.io.jaxb.GenericJaxbIO.<init>(GenericJaxbIO.java:81)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.io.jaxb.SolverConfigIO.<init>(SolverConfigIO.java:27)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlReader(SolverConfig.java:207)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlInputStream(SolverConfig.java:182)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:122)
        at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource(SolverConfig.java:97)
        at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(SolverFactory.java:55)
```

I can work through these issues by adding @RegisterForReflection on my class calling `SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("solverConfig.xml")`, but it feels like these reflection registrations should not have to be a manual step. Currently I'm at `@RegisterForReflection(targets = {EnvironmentMode.class, RandomType.class, DomainAccessType.class})`, but I'm guessing there will be a lot more enums to add to that list... Should it really be this complex? I'm using the Quarkus Optaplanner dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
  <artifactId>optaplanner-quarkus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing it another way, I was able to solve the issue.

In my class that previously called `solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("solverConfig.xml")`, I now just inject the factory:

```
@Inject
SolverFactory<Schedule> solverFactory;
```

And moved the XML file name to application.properties instead:

```
quarkus.optaplanner.solver-config-xml=solverConfig.xml
```

Comment: And you can even remove that property because if that property doesn't exist, it defaults to `solverConfig.xml` and it will be picked up if it exists